# Jquery dialog getting closed after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have issue, Jquery dailog is getting closed after button click, I want to keep it open, When I use modal true option in jquery dialog it does't allow to click button inside the pop, seems like some zindex problem.Please see the code and suggest a solution.

On click of btnSave the dialog is getting close I want to keep it open even after button until user click close button.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowProcessPopup() {
        var dlg = $("#divDetails").dialog({
            title: "Show Details",
            width: 'auto',
            maxWidth: ' 500',
            height: 'auto',
            fluid: true, 
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {}, 
            open: function () {
                {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    }

</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowPopUp" Text="Show Dailog"  OnClick="btnShowPopUp_OnClick"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
<div id="divDetails" title="Details" style="display: none; z-index: 100000">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDescription"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
</div>
```

```
 protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void btnShowPopUp_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "none", "<script>ShowProcessPopup();</script>", false);
}
```

Comment: side issue, but why are you posting back in order to show a popup (even via an updatepanel)?? Why not just use `<button type="button" onclick="ShowProcessPopup()">Show Dialog</button>` instead of the entire `<UpdatePanel>` block? It's simple javascript, and one less trip to the server.

Comment: and your dialog is probably closing because the `<asp:Button>` is posting back to the server. Putting UseSubmitBehaviour= false simply changes the postback mechanism, it doesn't remove the postback. Change it to a normal HTML button, or handle its client-side click event and run event.preventDefault(). Then you can use ajax to save the data maybe, and keep the dialog open.

Comment: @ADyson This is  a sample created to resolve the popup issue, In actual app I have do something in a server before opening the popup even if the its client call the dialog closes.

Comment: I can't use ajax since I'm doing file upload from the popup, Since the window gets closed I'm unable to show messages to the user.

Comment: it's perfectly possible to upload files via ajax :-) . If you don't like that solution then you'll have to make the server-side re-open the popup at page load and display the message (similar to what you did with the RegisterClientScriptBlock I guess)

Comment: Ok..Thanks.Let me try.